# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory with php, mysql in docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, docker-compose

Using containers in docker, I try to access with php to a database and I get the error "No such file or directory".

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gexpenses
      MYSQL_USER: gexpenses
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - "3311:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./bd:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      - ./bd.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/bd.sql:ro
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: php_web
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./local/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
COPY ./local /usr/src/dst_folder
WORKDIR /usr/src/dst_folder
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpq-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
```

my connection in PHP

```
<?php

$usr = "gexpenses";
$pwd = "1234";

try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=3311;dbname=gexpenses", $usr, $pwd);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected succesfully";
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I tried to create a bridge connection in case it was a connection problem between containers.

I also tried to change from localhost to database in the php host config but it returns "Connection refused".

Another test was to use

```
docker inspect -f '{{.Name}} - {{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}}' $(docker ps -aq)

return:
/php_web - 172.20.0.3
/database_1 - 172.20.0.2
```

I have also tried changing localhost to 172.20.0.2 returning "Connection refused".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this you have to create a docker network to connect your containers. The containers must be in the same network to comunicate to each other.
If this not work please send the output of `docker network inspect web`

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345
      MYSQL_DATABASE: gexpenses
      MYSQL_USER: gexpenses
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
    ports:
      - "3311:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./bd:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      - ./bd.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/bd.sql:ro
    networks: web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: php_web
    links:
      - database
    volumes:
      - ./local/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - "8100:80"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks: web 
networks:
  web:
    external: false
```

Comment: you can change false to true and crate a network with `docker network create web`